# What is the best way to brake to maintain the rotors?

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor, driving

What bad braking habits will result in warped rotors? What braking habit will prevent that from happening? Lastly if rotors can go bad from bad braking is there a way to brake to correct them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the only bad habit which causes issues with brakes is if you ride the brakes. This means keeping your foot on the brake pedal when you are not meaning to use the brakes. This causes premature brake wear and can possibly result in warped rotors. It also results in a reduction in fuel mileage because you are continually holding your vehicle back. This won't *absolutely* result in warped rotors, but it can lead to it because of the overheating of your rotors without a chance of cooling down during driving.

In an automatic transmission car, people use their left foot to brake are most susceptible to this malady because the temptation is to rest your foot on the brake pedal, even when you're not using it. (NOTE: Not trying to tell people how to drive ... this doesn't happen with standard shift cars because you use your right foot to brake with. Same things goes if you brake with your right foot in an automatic.)

With most things mechanical, there's no technique to "unwarp" a rotor. This is because mechanical things don't usually fix themselves. Once it's broke you have to replace or repair parts to get it right.

Comment: Riding the shift pedal is also bad? on what parts?

Comment: @Muze - Different question. Believe it's been asked before, so you might research a little.